# Can a request interceptor create a http response in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am in process of creating Offline mode in an app. Whenever a http request is send, I would want an interceptor to detect the network state. If the state is no connectivity, I would want to create a mock response and make it feel like as if the response is coming from a server.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you are online or not by reading the status of the response in your interceptor, if its a 401 / 501/ etc:

```
var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {
   function success(response) {
      return response;
   }
   function error(response) {
      var status = response.status; // error code
      if ((status >= 400) && (status < 500)) {
         $rootScope.broadcast("AuthError", status);
         return;
      }
      if ((status >= 500) && (status < 600)) {
         $rootScope.broadcast("ServerError", status);
         return;
      }
      // otherwise
      return $q.reject(response);
   }
   return function (promise) {
      return promise.then(success, error);
   }
}]
```

There's another way, using html5, but I guess will not work on some browsers. This is done using navigator.onLine property, like:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  //I'm online
} else {
  I'm not online
}
```

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an object inside your request interceptor this will trigger a call to the responseError interceptor, passing the throwed object as its argument.

You have to find a way notify responseError interceptor that this is not a real error and that it should return a custom response.

The responseError interceptor can choose to recover error returning a response object o fail returning a rejected promise (check angular's $http interceptor docs)

EDIT: If you throw an object from request interceptor you can't avoid an error message in console. It's better to return a rejected promise passing config object as value and put extra information in it for responseError detect the special situation.